# Hook componentdidmount doesn't rerender component. What could be an issue

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have simple component, which takes two props: title and percent. I want dynamically show percent from 0 to whatever number is passed to component. What it does on me is increases from 0 to 1 and that is it and stop on there. Looks like it renders component, gets into `componentDidMount`, increases to by 1 and then doesn't rerender component even tho setState is fired. What could be an issue?

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

class ItemList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            percent: 0
        }
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        if (this.state.percent <= this.props.number)
            setTimeout(() => {
                this.setState({
                    percent: this.state.percent + 1
                })
            }, 200)
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <li className="skills__programmer__content__item">
                <div className="skills__programmer__content__item__name">{this.props.title}</div>
                <div className="skills__programmer__content__item__percent">{ this.state.percent + "%"} </div>
            </li>
        )
    }
}

ItemList.propTypes = {
    title: PropTypes.string,
    number: PropTypes.number,
}

export default ItemList;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want the component to continuously update to the prop passed in, you need to use `setInterval` instead of `setTimeout`. This way, the state will keep incrementing by 1 until it reaches the desired number. `setTimeout` only executes once by design.

Comment: cause my logic was setTimeout changes a state, it triggers rerendering a component and then it lunches new setTimeout in componentDidMOunt hook. I don't see where is mistake in my logic